# dependency injection in grpc server go

Tags: go, dependency-injection, grpc

Suppose we have a go api containing a grpc server implementation.

This grpc server method has to do a variety of tasks which needs to be abstracted as a different service within the same api.

Is there a way to inject this new service in the grpc server?

Sample code:

```
package grpcserver

func (g *GrpcServer) GrpcServerExample(ctx context.Context, r *grpcpackage.SampleGrpcRequest) (*grpcpackage.SampleGrpcResponse, error) {
    service := differentService{}   //how to inject this instead of creating here
    result := service.DoSomething()
    return nil,nil
}
```

Comment: If you're abstracting something away with the same API, why not pass interfaces around? However, if 2 components do 2 fundamentally different things, I think abstraction isn't the way forwards. Different things are handled by different components, not by an abstraction layer...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I don't want to put it in the service definition of `GrpcServerExample` in the proto file because `differentService` is internal to the api. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

You can inject the service into `GrpcServer` while registering the gRPC server.

```
package grpcserver

type GrpcServer struct {
    MyService Service
}

func (g *GrpcServer) GrpcServerExample(ctx context.Context, r *grpcpackage.SampleGrpcRequest) (*grpcpackage.SampleGrpcResponse, error) {
    service := g.MyService
    result := service.DoSomething()
    return nil,nil
}

func main() {
    s := grpcpackage.NewServer()

    grpcpackage.RegisterGrpcServer(s, &GrpcServer{
        // Inject Here
        MyService: &ServiceImpl{},
    })
}
```

service_interface.go

```
package grpcserver

type Service interface {
    DoSomething() int
}
```

service_impl.go

```
package grpcserver

type ServiceImpl struct {
}

func (s *ServiceImpl) DoSomething() int {
    return 123
}
```